# Criando novo array com objetos específicos de outro array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Em javascript eu tenho um array "cartasUsuario"  e preciso criar um novoArray  apenas com os valores do .texto que entrarão no cartasUsuario. Em algum momento preciso dar um .push e será acrescentado ao final do array cartasUsuario um objeto nesse modelo {texto: "A♠️", valor: 11}.

```
let cartasUsuario = []
let novoArray = []


(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {texto: "A♠️", valor: 11}
1: {texto: "2♥️", valor: 2}
2: {texto: "3♥️", valor: 3}
```

O que preciso fazer para criar outro array com o conteúdo concatenado que receber do .texto?

```
console.log(`${cartasUsuario[0].texto + cartasUsuario[1].texto + cartasUsuario[2].texto} = pontuação ${usuarioValor}`)
```

Eu poderia utilizar cartasUsuario[0].texto, cartasUsuario[1].texto etc mas ficaria muito grande quando entrarem mais cartas. Queria algo que resolvesse isso de maneira mais prática.

Comment: Realmente não entendi muito bem o que você está tentando fazer... Você quer concatenar todas as propriedades `texto` dos objetos do array `cartasUsuario` ou somar os números da propriedade `valor`? Tente **[edit]** a sua pergunta para torná-la um pouco mais clara. :-)

Comment: Você quer criar um novo array só com o atrubuto texto?

Comment: Tentei editar, mas é isso mesmo. Eu preciso concatenar todas as propriedades texto dos objetos do array cartasUsuario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para criar um novo array com apenas a propriedade texto é necessário iterar pelo array cartas e retornar o texto, isso pode ser feito assim:

```js
let cartasUsuario = [
{texto: "A♠️", valor: 11},
{texto: "2♥️", valor: 2},
{texto: "3♥️", valor: 3}
]

let novoArray = cartasUsuario.map(c => c.texto)

console.log(novoArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Consegui destravar aqui. Eu utilizei algo semelhante ao que o Ewerton Belo propos:

```
novoArray = Array.from(cartasUsuario, ({ texto }) => texto);
```

já resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado a todos!

Comment: Marque com o "✅" que aparece ao lado da resposta, a resposta mais adequada a sua pergunta. Além disso, caso queira concatenar e não saiba, pode usar o `join()`. Ficando `novoArray.join()`

Comment: Sou novo aqui, tô aprendendo ainda. Obrigado pela força, já marquei lá na sua resposta